# Counterexample to $\operatorname{Ln}\frac{1}{z}=-\operatorname{Ln}z$ for $z\ne 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

Is there a counterexample to
$$\operatorname{Ln}\frac{1}{z}=-\operatorname{Ln}z$$
where $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ and
$$\operatorname{Ln}z=\operatorname{Ln}|z|+i\operatorname{Arg}z$$
where $\operatorname{Ln}|z|$ is the unique real solution $x$ of $e^{x}=|z|$ and $-\pi\lt\operatorname{Arg}z\le\pi$?

It was easy to find a counterexample to
$$\operatorname{Ln}wz=\operatorname{Ln}w+\operatorname{Ln}z$$
which is $w=-1$ and $z=i$. But I have trouble finding a counterexample to $\operatorname{Ln}\frac{1}{z}=-\operatorname{Ln}z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $z= -1$ you have
$$
\operatorname{Ln}(z) = \operatorname{Ln} \frac 1z = i \pi \, .
$$

More precisely,
$$
\operatorname{Ln} \frac 1z = \ln \left|\frac 1z\right| + i\operatorname{Arg} \frac 1z
= - \ln |z| + i\operatorname{Arg} \frac 1z
$$
and
$$
\operatorname{Arg} \frac 1z = - \operatorname{Arg} z
$$
*unless* $\operatorname{Arg} z = \pi$.

So $\operatorname{Ln}\frac{1}{z}=-\operatorname{Ln}z$
holds exactly for all $z \in \Bbb C \setminus (-\infty, 0]$, that is for all non-zero complex numbers which are not on the negative real axis.